# Platform channel data casting flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am using platform channel to communicate flutter and native.
From Android Native, I am passing `HashMap<String, String>`

At flutter, side expecting `Map<String, dynamic>`

but I am getting the error

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

if I change `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` it works, but I want `Map<String, dynamic>` how to handle this.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: The same map I am using for DIO  network calls, as Header that accepts only map<string, dynamic>.

Comment: Is there any way to convert map<dynamic, dynamic> to map<string, dynamic> ?

Comment: `Map<dynamic, String> map` -->   `Map<String, String> map2 = map;`

Comment: Map<String, dynamic>.from(map)  worked for me